# Android Tool Bar Center using Effects in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.forms

I am trying to center the title of the page in Android in Xamarin forms. 
I have access to the tool bar and was able to set the font family. But I am not able to set the text alignment or gravity to center.

`var context = (Android.App.Activity)Forms.Context;
 var toolbar = context.Resources.GetIdentifier("toolbar", "id", context.PackageName);
 var view = context.FindViewById(toolbar);`

I tried the following:

ForegroundGravity

```
view.SetForegroundGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
```

Text Alignment

```
view.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
```

Access the Childs of the toolbar and set the direction and alignment.

```
if (view is ViewGroup)
{
    var g = view as ViewGroup;

    for (var i = 0; i < g.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        SetTypefaceToAllTextViews(g.GetChildAt(i), typeface);
        g.GetChildAt(i).TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
        g.GetChildAt(i).TextDirection = TextDirection.Rtl;

    }
}
```

The issue is that, I don't have direct access to the gravity of the title.

---

**EDIT #1:**

I added this code after casting the view and I can see the font is changing but it won't get centered or any other alignment for some reason

```
if (view is TextView)
{
    var tv = view as TextView;
    tv.Typeface = typeface;
    tv.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
    tv.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
}
```

---

**EDIT #2:**
I was able to add the following to the effect based on an answer below and it somehow centered the element but not exactly at the center. Somehow it's to the right side of the center unless if there are 2 icons in the toolbar on the right and the left side, then, the title will be really centered. Tested on Android 8. Also, I found this issue on a similar solution.

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/CustomNavigationBarSample/issues/3

Comment: I tried to use the styles but I found it complex to work with and not responding to my changes

Comment: You should find in your Android project this file `toolbar.axml`. Just use a `TextView` as a title in your XML

Comment: you mean that I have to add the TextView and access it from the MainActivity? like this <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Toolbar Title"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

Comment: This solution may work but I don't want to create new themes and the effects will allow me more control at runtime

Comment: hum.. How about you check if the var `g` is a `TextView`, cast it if it's true, and then try to access the `gravity` field

Comment: but I don't access to the gravity other than what I tried (foregroundGravity and text alignment)

Comment: @Greggz you could use `if(g is TextView t)`, that would already cast it. just a little sidenote

Comment: Cast the `ViewGroup` when you're iterating through the cycle, and see if you can work with

Comment: @sLw Nicee, pretty dope

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how your Effect is implemented, but the following custom renderer seems to work (the bit that is relevant to centering text is in the `ToolbarChildAdded` method):

```cs
public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            this.toolbar.ChildViewAdded -= ToolbarChildAdded;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var toolbarId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("toolbar", "id", Context.PackageName);
            this.toolbar = this.FindViewById(toolbarId) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
            this.toolbar.ChildViewAdded += ToolbarChildAdded;
        }
    }

    private void ToolbarChildAdded(object sender, ChildViewAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Child is Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView tv)
        {
            // identify the title text view and center it
            tv.LayoutParameters = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent, (int)GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check Edit #2 on my question

Comment: The title is not actually in the center if there is an icon on the left or right. Can you please suggest a way to space them correctly if there are childern in the toolbar?

Comment: scratch that, i did more testing. If the title is long, it will go to the right for some reason but if the title is small, it will be centred correctly.

Comment: I am awarding this answer not because it's the best but just to get the badge for manually awarding points. 

If someone have the same issue, i advice them to use the Custom Navigation Layout which will allow you to create your own layout in the toolbar. 
Ream more here: https://doumer.me/a-look-at-new-xamarin-forms-features/

Answer (score 1):

On Android, the Title View is not centered, there is a 16dp margin on the left. Any attempt to centre content will have to take this into account.

It is easier to reset this value using a custom renderer.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        var toolbarId = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("toolbar", "id", Context.PackageName);
        var toolbar = this.FindViewById(toolbarId) as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
        if (toolbar != null) toolbar.SetContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Ensure your toolbar layout is correctly referenced in your main activity

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        //etc
    }
}
```

Once this is done, it is easiest to use an Absolute Layout to position items as you would like them inside the title view

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        Padding="0"
        Margin="10,0,10,0">

        <Image
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,130,31"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            Source="logowhite.png">
        </Image>

        <ImageButton
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.5,32,32"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
            Margin="0"
            WidthRequest="32"
            Source="settingsicon.png"
            Clicked="OnImageButtonClicked">
        </ImageButton>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```